# Rails: form to build deep associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm trying to build an object that's three associations deep in one hit. The user has the option of adding more of the child objects if they want.

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stacks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stacks, allow_destroy: true
end

class Stack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_many :boxes, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :boxes, allow_destroy: true
end

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stack
  has_many :template_variables, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_variables, allow_destroy: true
end

class TemplateVariable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Now my controller for a new template looks like so:

```
def new
  @template = Template.new
  stack = @template.stacks.build
  box = stack.boxes.build
  box.template_variables.build
end
```

I'm hitting some roadblocks that are making me think there's a better way to do this. Objects beneath the `Stack` object aren't saved. The controller permits all the correct params.

```
params.require(:template).permit(:name,
  stacks_attributes: [:name, :direction, :order, :x, :y, :_destroy],
  boxes_attributes: [:name, :_destroy],
  template_variables_attributes: [:name, :box_name, :designator, :order_index, :_destroy])
```

It could be my forms are just partials rendered when necessary like so:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :stacks do |stack| %>
  <%= render 'stack_fields', f: stack %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to_add_fields '+ stack', f, :stacks %>
```

And subsequent relations are nested therein, like in the `stack_fields` partial:

```
<div style='background: #ccc; padding: 1em;'>
  <%= f.input :name  %>
  <%= f.input :direction %>
  <%= f.input :order %>
  <%= f.input :x %>
  <%= f.input :y  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to 'x', '#', class: 'remove_fields' %>

  <%= link_to_add_fields '+ box', f, :boxes %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :boxes do |b| %>
    <%= render 'box_fields', f: b %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So my question really is: is there a better way to achieve what I want than to battle uphill like this? Like, maybe there's a standard practice or a gem or something that helps with "deep" object relation creation?

Comment: You forms and objects are nested... but looks like your permit/require isn't nested in the same way... Have you had a look at the params that come through to your server logs to check they match up with your permit/require structure?

Comment: Oh, that's a good point, and that makes a lot of sense. I'll run a quick test now. Still, this does feel like I'm solving for something that might have been solved in a far better way somewhere else. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params aren't nested quite correctly, each object must be nested within its parent object. Currently you have them all nested within template. Try:

```
params.require(:template).permit(:name,
  stacks_attributes: [
    :name, :direction, :order, :x, :y, :_destroy, 
    boxes_attributes: [
      :name, :_destroy, 
      template_variables_attributes: [
        :name, :box_name, :designator, :order_index, :_destroy
      ]
    ]
  ]
)
```

It is generally recommended that deep association only goes as far as 2 levels. However sometimes it is unavoidable. Not knowing the context of your data modelling makes it difficult to consider whether an alternative approach is possible.